# apiversion changed after kubectl create

Tags: kubernetes

In kubernetes 1.8, when I create a deployment for example

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2 # for versions before 1.8.0 use apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Then when I do a

```
kubectl get deploy nginx-deployment -o yaml
```

I got

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "1"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-01-24T01:01:01Z

....
```

Why the apiversion is extension/v1beta1 instead of apiVersion: apps/v1beta2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you create a deployment, the apiserver persists it and is capable of converting the persisted deployment into any supported version.

`kubectl get deployments` actually requests the extensions/v1beta1 version (you can see this by adding --v=6)

To get apps/v1beta2 deployments, do `kubectl get deployments.v1beta2.apps`

Comment: just want to say thank you sir for your answer. It makes a lot of senses now

Answer (score 0):

You might use an old version of `kubectl`.
If so, please upgrade your `kubectl` to 1.8, then create the `deployment` again.

Comment: I did use kubectl version 1.8.6